# How to debug what keeps NodeJS process alive

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have some serious bunch of asynchronous operations running, but NodeJS process is just not exiting when supposedly all have been done. Can I somehow find out what keeps it running? Can I see heap stack of running process somehow? Or can you give me tips what are the most usual causes of such idlings?

I don't have any kind of server running there, but I am using `async.nextTick` quite extensively which basically uses `setImmediate`. I am not sure if this can somehow get stuck. Also there are no connections to any kind of database or remote server. It's just process that does some work on file system.

Maybe there is some recursive loop, but I have tried using *node-inspector* and paused execution after it was stuck and it didn't showed me any point in code where it would hanging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at process._getActiveHandles() and process._getActiveRequests()

Comment: Thanks, that looks definitely interesting, especially that `_getActiveHandles`. Although I kinda fixed issue in the meantime and I am even sure how. But I am expecting it will happen again eventually, so this will come in handy.